# freelancing/remote work for German speaking countries

Tags: freelance-websites, germany

What's the best way to find German speaking customers that would require me to use German language proficiency?

Any opinions and suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: As a heads up, this sort of question may be regarded as off-topic in the near future. We've opened a [meta](http://meta.freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/221/9) topic to discuss whether or not to create this off-topic reason. Please give us your feedback!

Comment: I will rephrase, I didn't want to specifically ask for work, but ask where people could find it if they're German speakers, would that still be considered as self advertising?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

being a German freelance developer myself I know about your problem. The idea of freelancing has not yet gotten into many heads in Germany. People are very used and happy with dependent work at companies because a typical German is very fond of reliability. 
There is not yet a really good German website for freelance projects, you might try

https://www.etengo.de/
https://www.freelancer.de/

However I would suggest you to post on a big international platform a job offer like oDesk in German language. Some Germans are there.